# Cascading expression in AngularJS works with ng-show but not with ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The following block of code work if I use `ng-show` to display sections but not with the desired `ng-if`

```
<div ng-controller="nullController">
  <button ng-click="p = 1">click to reveal next</button>
</div>

<div ng-show="$$prevSibling.p == 1" ng-controller="nullController">
  <div>Appears based on previous sibling state</div>
  <button ng-click="p = 1">click to reveal next</button>
</div>

<div ng-show="$$prevSibling.p == 1" ng-controller="nullController">
  <div>Appears based on previous sibling state</div>
  <button ng-click="p = 1">click to reveal next</button>
</div>
```

[See in Plunker ng-show](http://plnkr.co/edit/cWlHbgunTSFt1xb7GF6V?p=preview)

[See in Plunker ng-if](http://plnkr.co/edit/K5pUcpSu5VDxjaMhseFV?p=preview)

UPDATE: someone pointed out that the version of the angularjs lib in the plank did not have ng-if. Now I have updated to use 1.2.x the problem however did not go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You are using angularjs 1.0.1** !

`ng-if` didn't exist in this old version yet.

Only the versions **above 1.1.5** handle the `ng-if` directive.

You really should rather choose this version (the latest stable one) for your plunkr for instance:

`<script data-require="angular.js@1.2.16" data-semver="1.2.16" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>`

[Here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/2f96fbd17577685bc013a4f7ced06664af253944)'s a more official data to show that `ngIf` was available since 1.1.5.

Furthermore, pay attention that `ngIf` creates a new child scope.
Indeed, it needs this mechanism in order to achieve the **delete** of the component from the DOM.
`ng-show` does not need it since it simply **hide** the content.

Thus, `$$prevSibling` would not target the expected scope, since called from a deeper scope in the scopes' hierarchy.

Comment: Updated the plank. That partly solved on not being initially hidden, yet this does not work - sections do not reveal as expected.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out version differencies. But please remove this answer as this is not the source of the error..

Comment: It's your expression acting as the condition that does not work.

Comment: @PeterAronZentai https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/kPRzdcrIzNw  `ng-show` does not created a child scope, but `ng-if` does.

Comment: yes - thank you. this must be the case. and against all reasoning, it is simply a bug in angularjs

Comment: Why may it be a bug??

Comment: A conceptual break caused by some kind of implementation level problem. It is clear to see that from the developer perspective no one would expect ng-show to behave not the same way as ng-if.

Comment: ng-show hide the content, ng-if remove it. IMO, it's a different thing. But it's sure that it'd be better if there wasn't this "stuff to know" :)